# jQuery Chosen change popup count items

Tags: jquery

i'm currently using Chosen jQuery plugin in project. by default count of viewed itemd after click on `select` is 10. and i'm trying to change it to 5, how to do that?

```
var config = {
    '.chosen-select': {},
    '.chosen-select-deselect': {allow_single_deselect: true},
    '.chosen-select-no-single': {disable_search_threshold: 10},
    '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text: 'not found!'},
    '.chosen-select-width': {width: "100%"}
}
for (var selector in config) {
    $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @JqueryKing i can not find how to do that

Comment: Unclear you are asking

Comment: @mahdipishguy : can you please put some code hint.

Comment: @Lalitpatadiya i'm pasting some default setting for Chosen

Comment: @mahdipishguy : you mean you want item in list is 5..?

Comment: @Lalitpatadiya yes sir, foe example i have 20 item in list. i want to limit window list to 5

Comment: @mahdipishguy : after 5 what about other..? that you want in scrollbar or not..?

Comment: @mahdipishguy : try size="5" in your selectbox

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
For example : 
<select name="reg_email" id="cars" size="3">
                <option>TOYOTA</option>
                <option>HOLDEN</option>
                <option>TATA</option>
                <option>ALFA ROMEO</option>
                <option>CITROEN</option>
                <option>HONDA</option>
                <option>JEEP</option>
                <option>SUZUKI</option>
            </select>
```

add size attribute and add limit like size='5'.

I hope this will help you.